# spring-boot and AspectJ based LTW without Java agent

Tags: spring-boot

I've been having very hard time trying to make it work on my end. What I want to achieve is bringing up my spring-boot project that would weave all Java classes with AspectJ when I just run "java -jar app.jar" (Tomcat 8 embedded is used) without any Java agent params.

Is this generally possible? And if yes, what are the required config stuff that should be paid attention to?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible, but you would probably (at a minimum) need a custom `main()` method that created an LTW classloader and used that to launch your app. The default classloader in the `java -jar` would not be LTW-enabled. Any reason you don't want to use an agent (since you obviously control the launcher)?

Comment: Thank you Dave for the answer. This indeed comes down to using LTW aware classloader, I just thought maybe spring-boot addresses that scenario in some graceful way. The main reason of not using an agent is sticking to a minimalistic commnd line for running the app from an executable JAR.

Comment: just taken a look at spring-boot sources, and it looks like it crafts a special classloader that theoretically could be AspectJ LTW aware. This sounds like a potential spring-boot feature, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Here a library that initializes aspectj and spring-aspects at runtime by injecting instrumentation: https://github.com/subes/invesdwin-instrument

You can use it as a sample.